# で in 完全変態で、生まれ変わったように

Tags: grammar, meaning

I'm looking for some help in understanding the sentence below. To provide a bit more context one of the characters シュン made a ”変態発言” and then the following exchange occurred:

> Girl 1「”変態”って何ですか？」
>
> Girl 2「”さなぎから蝶になる”って意味よ」
>
> Girl 3「正確には完全変態」
>
> Girl 4「せんぱいって完全変態するんだぁ」
>
> Girl 1「シュン君は完全変態**で**、生まれ変わったように頑張るんですね」

I get the idea behind the exchange where 完全変態 is used to mean something like Complete Pervert(referring to him being a pervert) / Complete Metamorphosis(as in a type of metamorphosis in which the larva does not resemble the adult). However what I've gotten myself confused on is how to properly parse the last sentence.

I think I've just confused myself but anyway, is this で just simply であって and not the で that is used with definitions like 動作・作用の原因・理由を表す,  動作・作用の手段・方法・材料などを表す。…を使って.

Comment: I think here で means something like was/were(as a matter of fact)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Girl 1: What does “hentai” mean?

Girl 2: It’s when a pupa turns into a butterfly.

Girl 3: Technically that’s “total hentai”.

Girl 4: Huh, so senpai goes through total hentai.

Girl 1: I see. Shun-kun is a total hentai, and that’s why he tries his best as though he was reborn.

Girl 1 makes the connection that he tries as hard as he does because he’s a total hentai. I think this is a であって usage of で and it somewhat expresses a cause/reason. It’s a little different from 風で木が倒れた, where 風 is the 原因 for 木が倒れた, and で would *not* mean であって because 風 is not being equated with anything. In シュン君は完全変態で, there is an equation of two nouns, and hence this で can be interpreted as the て form of だ. One of the usages of the て form is to express a cause, e.g. 多すぎて in “人が多すぎて友達が見当たらない” (There’s too many people -> I can’t find my friend.)